# If I am creating an assignment on Google Classroom using a form that has been shared with me, who will see the submissions?

Tags: google-classroom

My team and I have divided and conquered with creating assignments on Google Classroom using Forms. If we all share out the same form, will I see just my students or will all students show up?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask.

Answer (score 0):

### Who will see the submissions?

[image]

- When collaborating on a shared form and enabling the option `Get email notifications for new responses` - the notifications will be received by the editor who enabled with option for the given form - in this case you.
- Thereby, you will receive ALL the notifications for form submissions - no matter who created the assignment and posted the form filling URL.
- Analogously, all the other collaborators that enable the option "`Get email notifications for new responses" will receive ALL form submissions
- In addition, all collaborators will have access to the destination spreadsheet where the responses are stored.

### If you want to avoid this:

- Rather then using the shared form, make a copy of it
- Obtain and use the new response URL belonging to the new copy
- Select your own destination spreadsheet that is not shared with anyone
- Nobody other than you will have access to the form submissions made to your private copy of the shared form.

[image]